# Gradle 4.4 requires Java 7 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 6

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I imported a gradle project, from Kotlin Koans Project. Attempting to run the project Gives the Error "Gradle 4.4 requires Java 7 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 6."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by `Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S` to `Project Structure` 
And changing the java version to 9.0 [image]

Comment: For anyone else with the same issue: I had to change it here and in the Gradle settings